# Drupal 8 translation for routing titles

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

In Drupal 8, I installed all translation modules (Configuration Translation, Content Translation, Interface Translation, Language) and cleared all caches and run cron again.

But the titles defined in routing YML files are still missing from the User interface translation configuration page (/admin/config/regional/translate)

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out.

After installing all above modules, we still have to visit the page defined by the routing and switch it to another language (non-English).

Then system would automatically pick up all strings in the page needed to translate, including the title.

The source string is case sensitive.